# OHLC python chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, trading, ohlc

I'm new to pandas and matplotlib and I'm trying to code some algorithmic trading.

I bought [this course](https://www.udemy.com/course/python-for-finance-and-trading-algorithms/), and now I understand more, BUT...

It does not includes sample code for OHLC chart in intraday (I mean, it is not complete)

And there are others problems that i have like that my native language is not English (there is no quality material in Spanish about those libraries)

All the material that I found online only plots "daily chart" and is based in `matplotlib.finance`, and now it is deprecated, currently python uses `mplfinance`.

Please I need a sample code to chart the csv file in seconds, minutes, hours and days.

I really had tried, I'm not a lazy person, but is taking a lot of time just to plot  that chart, the course does not solve my requirement.

Here you have csv file for Alibaba (BABA) in 1 second, 5 second, 15 second, 30 second and 1 minute OHLC chart.

[My data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UwcGzgiSREnl0JfSPgrBDK8lwMc-1xRI)

Answer (score 0):

**MPLFINANCE**

You can use [`mplfinance`](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance). I tried it and it worked, here is the sample code.

**note**: you need to rename the column in your source data so the columns `Open`, `High`, `Low`, `Close` have uppercase in their first character.

```
import mplfinance as mpf
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('NYSE_BABA, 5s.csv', index_col=0)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
mpf.plot(data,type='candle')
```

Well yes the candlestick is difficult to see because we have the short range data, but you get the idea. Hope it helps!

[image]

---

**PLOTLY**

You might want to consider [Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/candlestick-charts/) for a nicer visualization.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('NYSE_BABA, 5s.csv')
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'], unit='s')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=data['time'],
                open=data['Open'],
                high=data['High'],
                low=data['Low'],
                close=data['Close'])])

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks¡ i will take a look to the code , is there a way to make that the datetime(from year to second) appears in the "x" axis? , is the only thing that i can not do until now.

Comment: @want_code_that I edited the answer, you can take a look how to do it using plotly

Comment: Thanks dzakyputra i think that this is a good begginning point